# Plot only those regions where a function's value is positive

Tags: plotting

I want to plot only those portions of the following function in which the function is positive (e.g. from $0-0.01$ & $0.02-0.03$ and so on):

$$230\sqrt{2}\sin\left(100\pi t\right)$$

In addition to that, I want to create some dotted lines in the plot with values next to it!

How can I do this in one *Mathematica* expression?

My code so far:

```
Plot[{230 Sqrt[2] Sin[100 Pi*t]}, {t, 0, 40*10^(-3)}]
```

Comment: Look up `Plot` in the help files and try it out. The help files should be your first go-to when learning new software, and *Mathematica*'s are particularly good.

Comment: I've done that, and I can't -> that's why I choose to ask it here

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by "positive sides" and why you indicate non-contiguous intervals. You say that you did obtain a plot already: please include the code that worked so far in your question, as a starting point.

Comment: Then it's a good idea to post what you tried.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might give you something to work on as a start.

```
Plot[
  230 Sqrt[2] Sin[100 Pi t], {t, 0, 0.03},
  GridLines -> {{0, 0.01, 0.02}, {-100, 250}},
  GridLinesStyle -> {{Dashed, Red}, {Dotted, Blue}},
  Epilog -> {
    Red, Text[Style[0.01, FontSize -> 18], {0.01, 310}, Background -> White],
    Blue, Text[Style[250, FontSize -> 24], {0.025, 250}, Background -> White]
  },
  ImageSize -> Large
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'd suggest that you look up all functions and options used in the code above to familiarize yourself with them and to adapt them to your needs.

---

You can show only the positive portion of the plot in two ways, either by using a `PlotRange` option as suggested by george2079, or by specifying a `RegionFunction` ([see docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html)), with slightly different results.

```
(* with a RegionFunction *)
Plot[
  230 Sqrt[2] Sin[100 Pi t], {t, 0, 0.03},
  RegionFunction -> (#2 >= 0 &)
]
```

[image: RegionFunction]

```
(* with PlotRange *)
Plot[230 Sqrt[2] Sin[100 Pi t], {t, 0, 0.03},
  PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, `PlotRange` restricts the region of space shown; `RegionFunction` instead does not alter the plot range, but simply only shows points that conform to the condition specified.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help, but the only thing I dont know is to cut the negative values (in the interval: 0.010 to 0.020) out of the plot?

Comment: `PlotRange->{0,Automatic}`

Comment: @JanEerland I modified my answer to include your request. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Wow it worked! Thanks a lot!